# How to cap this model in 3ds max?

Tags: 3ds-max

[image]

The above model was originally a closed surface, but I removed its upper face. The red lines selected are its boundary. They are in the same plane.

Now I want to cap this hole. When I select its boundray edge and click 'Cap', I get 5 separate faces: One rectangle and four circles.

[image]

But what I want is one face with four holes. How can I do this?